# .htaccess rules to have wordpress in root and cakephp in subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, cakephp, subdirectory

i installed wordpress in the root directory of my FTP, and then in a subfolder I install cakephp, however I have a problem with htaccess.

```
www/
.htacess
(wordpress)
/folderCakephp/
              .htacess
              (cakephp)
```

Wordpress htaccess :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Cakephp root htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Cakephp app/ htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Cakephp app/webroot/ htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

the problem is that when I go on www.domain.com/folderCakephp/ I have a Wordpress 404

Comment: the problem is that when I go on www.domain.com/folderCakephp/ I have a Wordpress 404

Comment: try RewriteBase / in all cakephp .htaccess files

Comment: I just take the RewriteBase / and nothing changes ...

Comment: I got it usefull.+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the directory where WordPress is installed, i editing the .htaccess file and i have add the following line. (CakePHP subdirectory will be called "cake")

Wordpress `.htaccess`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^cake/(.*)$ /cake/$1 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

/cake `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /cake
 RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
 RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

/app `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /cake
 RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
 RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

/app/webroot `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /cake
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

That’s it. You’re good to go.

Visiting example.com in the browser will open your WordPress website, while example.com/cake/, depending on how you configured it, will open your CakePHP app.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the last line in your WordPress rewrites

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This rewrites **everthing** that isn't picked up by another rule to WordPress.  I think you want to change this to match everything but the cakePHP folder using a negative match.  I have not tested this, but it should be something like

```
RewriteRule (?<!folderCakephp). /index.php [L]
```